# Java XmlRpc server fails with NoSuchMethodException for Encodings.isRecognizedEncoding

Tags: java, xml-parsing, xerces, xalan

org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcServer is failing with NoSuchMethod exception on incoming request:

`Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xml.serializer.Encodings.isRecognizedEncoding(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
api-server_1      |     at org.apache.xml.serializer.dom3.LSSerializerImpl.write(LSSerializerImpl.java:926)`

The classpath includes

> xalan-j2-serializer.jar

with

```
    sh-4.2# jar tvf xalan-j2-serializer.jar | grep Encodings   
    7717 Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 UTC 1980 org/apache/xml/serializer/Encodings.class
11598 Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 UTC 1980 org/apache/xml/serializer/Encodings.properties
```

Encodings.class decompiles:

```
sh-4.2# javap org.apache.xml.serializer.Encodings
Compiled from "Encodings.java"
public final class org.apache.xml.serializer.Encodings {  
        ...
        public org.apache.xml.serializer.Encodings();
        ...
        public static boolean isRecognizedEncoding(java.lang.String);
        ...
```

The server is running in docker, on a Centos:7 image. OpenJDK Java 8. 
The client is a Python2.7 script, calling xmlrpclib.ServerProxy.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error message.

I was using Axis2, and I found this in the Axis2 [FAQ](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/faq.html#f1)

> This happens specifically with Tomcat 4.x and 5.0 in a JDK 1.5 environment. The reason is that the system picks up a wrong transformer factory class. This can be solved simply by putting the xalan-2.7.0.jar into the axis2/WEB-INF/lib directory

I replaced my *xalan* to version 2.7.1.

Same error message was reported in [OpenSAML](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/opensaml-users/0GrgysSumSk).
It was resolved by updating xalan to version 2.7.1, too.

Comment: Installing xalan-2.7.1. directly from Apache repo doesn't seem to help. 
I have removed xalan-2j-serializer.jar and xalan-2.jar that came with openJDK 8.0 and installed xalan-2.7.1.  Same error.